# How to restore GPT backup on Linux?

Tags: backup, restore, gpt

Today, I've encountered a problem when trying to install Windows7 on my new laptop. The installer claimed that Windows couldn't be installed on a GPT drive, so I tried to turn the partition table into MBR. I backed up the partition, and created a new msdos partition table on GParted, but that removed all my partitions, including my backup one.

How can I restore my partition table backup? I've tried using gdisk, gpart and sgdisk.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a new laptop, there shouldn't be any issues with support for GPT.  You may have an issue with the BIOS.  Please see this link for more information.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336946.aspx